# Mocking a script with no `if __name__=="__main__":` block

Tags: python, mocking, monkeypatching

Suppose I have files `main.py` and `common.py` in my root directory. These represent third party modules which I would not like to touch for the time being. Suppose I also have a `test.py` file which I'd like to use to test `main.py`.

`common.py` contains the following:

```
def hello():
  print("hello")
```

`main.py` contains the following:

```
from common import hello

hello()
```

Is there a way to monkey patch the `hello` function in `test.py` such that importing `main.py` will use the mocked function? For instance, I'd like to monkey patch `hello` to print out `goodbye`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty straightforward:

```
import common

common.hello = lambda: print("goodbye")

import main
```

Comment: Note this relies on knowing that `main.py` imports `common` before calling `hello`. In general, there's no opportunity to patch anything between the `import` statement and the module being created from the contents of the file.